# When using rpy.robjects a message comes up "Unable to determine R home: [WinError 2] The system could not find the specified file"

Tags: python, r, windows, rpy2

I'm implementing a simple function in python with the rpy2 API.

In VScode I manage to print a confidence interval, calculating Z-statistic calling the function created with the robjects as seen in the pic. But before the printed value I get the message "Unable to determine R home: [WinError 2] The system could not find the specified file". The same message appears in Jupyter but doesn't allow me to print anything at all, when calling a rpy2 function it get the error "Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure'>'".

Also just importing the package itself "import rpy2.robjects" retrives the same message. Import rpy2 alone doesn't show up anything.

I tried to add Rscript.exe and R.exe path to system variables but didn't work, neither of them (not sure if I did it properly), tried to reinstall R, didn't work.

Any clue on how to solve this?

[Image of the function being used and it's output in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0yht.png)
[The output for the same function as before but in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzSkA.png)

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the error is that Windows R has changed its registry structure and it made the current `rpy2`'s R install path detection obsolete. I've pushed a [PR](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/pull/889) to address this issue, but for the meantime your solution is to set `R_HOME` environmental variable.

Here is what you could do:

```py
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = r"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.0" # change as needed
import rpy2
```

As long as you run the `os.environ...` line before importing any `rpy2` module, you should be good to go.

On a side note, you can also set `os.environ["R_LIBS_USER"]` to use per-user library path.

Comment: I too am facing the same issue and tried to implement what you had mentioned but it doesn't seem to still work for me.

Comment: That's curious. Is it with Python or Jupyter? In any case, post a new question and I can try to help you.

Comment: If you are using Jupyter, see if [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575015) helps.