# Unable to determine R library path

Tags: python, r, windows, jupyter-lab, rpy2

I am new to R. I am running Jupyter Lab on a Windows 11 machine, and have created a virtual environment where I installed some packages and irkernel. I get the following message when I execute `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`:

```
Unable to determine R library path: Command '('C:\\Users\\ephra\\miniconda3\\envs\\cde\\Lib\\R\\bin\\Rscript', '-e', 'cat(Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:\\Users\\ephra\\miniconda3\\envs\\cde\\Lib\\R'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:\\Users\\ephra\\miniconda3\\envs\\cde\\Lib\\site-packages\\rpy2' 

from src.setup import *

%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R 
library(tidyverse)
```

Apart from the environment variables, the above code comes from David Mertz book "Cleaning Data for Effective Data Science". I need your help.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with this specific issue but if your looking to combine R and Python I would highly recommend using RMarkdown notebooks in RStudio. It takes a lot of the pain out of trying to use the two languages together.

Comment: rpy2 does not seem to be supported for windows. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is something you have in unix and unix-like OS's, but not windows. From the rpy2 documentation: *Running rpy2 on Windows is currently not supported although relative success was recently reported with the lastest in the 3.3.x series.* Referene: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/overview.html#installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: This is a speculative answer as I don't use Jupyter*

That `os.environ` trick works for me in plain Python but Jupyter's magic routine `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` utilizes `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to set itself up. The error comes from the fact that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is Linux/Unix thing hence the trouble.

**Failed Attempt #1**

<strike>What you may be able to do is to add the following line to your `os.environ` calls:</strike>

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = 'C:\\Users\\ephra\\miniconda3\\envs\\cde\\Lib\\R\\bin\\x64'
```

Assuming 'C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\cde\Lib\R\bin' exists. If not, look for a R subfolder with bunch of exe and dll files.

**Attempt #2**

Surveying further, I noticed that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` itself is never used by `rpy2`, and it appears to be a Linux workaround. So, what happens if you comment out Lines 26-28 of `Lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py`?

The lines should read

```py
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = (rpy2.situation.r_ld_library_path_from_subprocess(R_HOME)
                   if R_HOME is not None
                   else '')
```

If this hack succeeds, let me know and I can file a PR.

Comment: I added the line but still get the message "Unable to determine R library path: Command '('C:\\Users\\ephra\\miniconda3\\envs\\cde\\Lib\\R\\bin\\Rscript', '-e', 'cat(Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))')' returned non-zero exit status 1."

Comment: OK. That's too bad, but I see why my idea doesn't work... If you are gun ho about getting this to work, you can try another hack idea in my updated answer above

Comment: The hack has succeeded: the "os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ..." in the os.environ has been removed and I did commented out Lines 26-28 of Lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py as you suggested. I really appreciate!

Comment: Good to hear. I've added this workaround to my pending PR (which fixes the auto detection issue) so hopefully it'll be fixed in the future releases.

Comment: good research. appears to be a related open issue here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/875