# Having problems using rpy2 in Jupyter notebook with Mac M1

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am having problems importing rpy2 in a Jupyter notebook using Mac M1. It doesn't seem that there is an issue if I run the code using python from the terminal. I am aware that many are having issues as well, for example [this issue on github](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/900), [this question on installing rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358650/how-to-correctly-install-rpy2-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), [issues with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575015/unable-to-determine-r-library-path), etc.

I have tried many things but none seem to work. My error message is also slightly different.

In sum, when I import `from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr`, I get the errors:

```
Unable to determine R library path: Command '('/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/bin/Rscript', '-e', 'cat(Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))')' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
```

followed by

```
OSError: cannot load library '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib': dlopen(/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/libblas.3.dylib'
Referenced from: '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib'
Reason: tried: '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/../../libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/lib/../../libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/python3.11/site-packages/../../libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/bin/../lib/libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libblas.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libblas.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

In the issue raised in the GitHub link, their error message was related to the compatibility issue of using the intel-based R vs m1 chip-based R. I don't get that error here.

I have tried installing `r-base`, `r-essentials` via conda as people have pointed out but it still doesn't work.

I also tried setting the R-path, based on the error message, as:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/'
```

but it still complains.

I find the error message strange given that the path

```
/Users/mydir/miniconda3/envs/ds_project/lib/R/bin/Rscript
```

exists on my local machine.

Could this be an issue with my IDE, Vscode? Or with Jupyter notebook (My jupyterlab version is 3.6.5)? As mentioned above, I don't run into problems running this on python on the terminal. My R installation is also located in

```
/opt/R/arm64/
```

but I have

```
/opt/R/x86_64/
```

available as well.

I would greatly appreciate any help/suggestions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by exporting the R_HOME variable as in: [enter link description here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-fix-import-error-while-loading-rpy2-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook-on-mac-osx/)